# Drawing an SVG dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to draw an isoceles triangle with it's top vertex in the middle of the screen.

I want to use JavaScript as screen sizes of different users can be different and hence, center of the screen must first be found out.

Here is my code:

```
function drawRect(){

        var w = $(document).width();
        var h = $(window).height();
        var halfh = h/2;
        var halfw = w/2;
        var svg = document.createElement("svg");
        var poly = document.createElement("polygon");
        svg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed;");
        svg.setAttribute("height", ""+h);
        svg.setAttribute("width", ""+w);
        poly.setAttribute("points", ""+halfw+","+halfh+" 0,"+h+" "+w+","+h);
        poly.setAttribute("style", "fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1");
        svg.appendChild(poly);

        var svgplace = document.getElementById("carpet");
        svgplace.appendChild(svg);
     }
```

No triangle appears on the screen. But, if I open the 'Inspect Element' console on chrome, and I modify the created html element slightly, it appears! (Any kind of small mod. Like adding a space in the middle somewhere)

Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the attributes -- does anything change?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290392/creating-svg-markers-programatically-with-javascript

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way? Use a viewBox and then you can have fixed co-ordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
```

`SVG` is in its own namespace aside from `HTML`.  Therefore, you need to create elements that are in the `SVG` namespace using [`createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS).

---

Consider the following example that works in `Chrome` and `Firefox`

```js
var newItem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
newItem.setAttribute("cx", ((16 * 1) + 8));
newItem.setAttribute("cy", "50%");
newItem.setAttribute("r", 4);
newItem.setAttribute("fill", "#333333");

document.getElementById("target").appendChild(newItem);
```

```html
<svg id="target">
</svg>
```